# Is there an Event Listener for form Submit complete?

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener

Anyone know what, if any, event might be triggered when a Form Submit is complete.  This is a returning a 204 (No Content) response so no new onload or DOMContentLoaded because no actual content.

Thanks,

Comment: um, if you submit a form the new page would load so the page that fired it would no longer be around.....

Comment: You can only do that if you form is submitted by Ajax -> success

Comment: If an http 204 response is returned a new page is not loaded

Comment: @MaxZoom is correct. The only way you would be able to read the response of your form is if you intercepted the submit and sent the form submission as an XHR request. You do this with jQuery using $(selector-of-form).on('submit', function) or with javascript using event listeners on your form.

Comment: @Dondrey Taylor that XHR method is what I am trying to avoid.  A form can be submitted successfully and an http 204 response can be returned which stops the page content changing.  Only problem is how to return a success/fail flag and find an appropriate event listener to fire when submit is complete.